# How to check Trace or log file in YII?

Tags: php, logging, yii

I Want to use log functionality from YII and i am new to YII.

Can anyone guide me where is file location of logging content? or tracing content?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using default Yii `main.php` file then all the logs go to your `protected/runtime/application.log` file. It will include standard Yii logs as well as you own `Yii::log()` calls too.

Comment: Thank you for this help. But i am getting blank white screen while adding data to user table. i want to find error. How can i? can you help me?

Comment: you should also keep the path of your php runtime error log file based on your server setup. If it's apache, you can find php errors in error_log. Then look into the yii runtime log. Yii can only catch runtime errors. For compile time/syntax errors are only reported in php error log, which I think is why you see blank screen.